# Restore state snapshot running out of disk space

Tags: cardano-db-sync

I'm following this guide to restore the latest state of the chain to my local machine
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/blob/master/doc/state-snapshot.md

while running the restore job as the following command. it consumes significant amounts  of free disk space

```
PGPASSFILE=config/pgpass-mainnet scripts/postgresql-setup.sh --restore-snapshot /Users/manhdt/Downloads/db-sync-snapshot-schema-13.1-block-9348936-x86_64.tgz /Users/manhdt/ledger-state/mainnet
```

Included 53GB of the latest snapshot https://update-cardano-mainnet.iohk.io/cardano-db-sync/index.html#13.1/. My Macbook (32 GB RAM, 512GB SSD) still has over 320GB of free disk space. However, it reduces pretty fast and my Mac runs out of space after a while (approximately 1 -> 2 hours).

Does anyone could help to pass this issue?

Thank you

Comment: I am not aware of any work around from this other than providing extra disk space. Maybe a temporary (ie, just during the restore operation) external disk may be a solution.

Comment: Thanks. I've removed the compressed file during the insertion process to claim extra space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snapshot file will be copied to another folder during the insertion process. Then it's safe to delete it to claim more than 50Gi free space.

Thanks